# Can we apply to the Marie Curie postdoc fellowship with two proposals supported by two different faculty members at two different universities?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job, marie-curie

I'm thinking of applying to the Marie Curie postdoc fellowship. I've been to [their FAQ page](https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/topic-details/horizon-msca-2023-pf-01-01;callCode=null;freeTextSearchKeyword=MSCA%20;matchWholeText=true;typeCodes=1,0;statusCodes=31094501,31094502,31094503;programmePeriod=null;programCcm2Id=null;programDivisionCode=null;focusAreaCode=null;destinationGroup=null;missionGroup=null;geographicalZonesCode=null;programmeDivisionProspect=null;startDateLte=null;startDateGte=null;crossCuttingPriorityCode=null;cpvCode=null;performanceOfDelivery=null;sortQuery=sortStatus;orderBy=asc;onlyTenders=false;topicListKey=topicSearchTablePageState), but I didn't see a question that addresses the possibility for the same candidate who wishes to submit two (or more) research proposals with two different future mentors at two different (or same) institutions. Thus I wonder whether it's possible at all?

Marie Curie association never replies, I tried emailing them before; so how could I check this?

Comment: In my experience, funding agencies always forbid applicants from sending in two applications if they cannot accept both awards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should read the *Guide for applicants* of the MSCA-PF very carefully if you want to increase your chances of getting the award.
In the 2023 edition at p. 7 they clearly state that:

> Only one proposal per individual researcher can be submitted. In case
> of several proposals involving the same individual researcher, only
> the last submitted proposal will be considered eligible. However,
> please note that the same supervisor and a host institution can be
> involved in more than one proposal in the same call.

But the *Guide* also contains a lot of other absolutely vital info if you plan to apply!

If you need to ask any other questions, you can try to contact the National Contact Point (NCP) of your country. In my experience they respond very quickly, but I guess it can vary from country to country.

Finally I would suggest you to contact your potential supervisor as soon as possible. And keep in mind that most research institution need to approve your application first, and this can also take time.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It’s part of the requirements that you submit only one proposal. So don’t get into trouble submitting two. My advice will be to submit the same proposal for another fellowship. There are so many fellowships out there that you could actually submit a new application to.